# Charge 3.7 Li-ion Battery with 5V battery charger?

Tags: arduino, batteries, charger, lithium-ion, 5v

Is it possible/save to charge a 3.7V Li-ion Battery with a 5V battery charger like this one: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B0191EVW0C/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Additional question: Would this be sufficient for an Arduino Pro Mini 5V using the VCC Pin?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest not mix battery chemistries.  That said, what is the "Akku" part of "Lithium-Akku" mean?  Is this German for something?

Comment: Post this question to the Amazon supplier.  EE.SE isn't his volunteer application support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this charger is okay for a single 3,6-4,2V li-ion cell. An ATmega328 will run fine at this voltage when you obey the clock speed limit ([section 29.3 of the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)). Make sure to measure battery voltage using the Arduino, so you don't discharge the battery too deep.